# To Do List prioritization using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I keep my To Do list in Google Sheets.  It contains three columns: item to do, date added, and priority.  As I enter a new item to the list, the date cell is auto populated with the day's date and the list auto sorts ascending on the number in the priority column.

When I add a new item to the list, and assign it a priority number, I have to manually increment by +1 the number of the entries after the one I added.

**For example**: priorities 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 become 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5 when I assign the value of 2 to a new item on the list.

I'd like to find a way for the numbers after the added entry to increment by +1 automatically so that 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5 becomes 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.

Over the last week I have searched multiple times for ideas on how to do this with Google Apps Script.  I have not been successful.  I would appreciate some suggestions on how to accomplish this.

I consider myself a Google Apps Script beginner.

---

3/19/2022 - Based on Cooper's code, I have come up with the following which works well except for when I delete the contents of a cell, for example A5, and column C doesn't sort to take into account the fact that C5 is now blank.

```
function onEdit(e) {

var row = e.range.getRow();
var col = e.range.getColumn();

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Fred");

var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, ss.getLastRow() - 1, 3);

var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();


if(col == 1 && (cell.getValue().length < 1)){
e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,2).clearContent()
e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,3).clearContent()}

else if(col == 1 && (cell.getValue().length > 0)){
e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,2).setValue(new Date())};


var prg = ss.getRange("C2:C" + ss.getLastRow());
prg.clearDataValidations();
var pl = prg.getValues().flat();

var l = [...Array.from(new Array(pl.length + 2).keys(), x => x)];
//console.log(JSON.stringify(l));
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(l).build();
prg.setDataValidation(rule);

if (e.range.columnStart == 3 && e.range.rowStart > 2) {
ss.getRange("A2:C" + ss.getLastRow()).sort({ column: 3, ascending: true });
//Logger.log([...Array.from(new Array(ss.getLastRow()-1).keys(),x => [x + 1])]);
ss.getRange("C2:C" + ss.getLastRow()).setValues([...Array.from(new Array(ss.getLastRow()-1).keys(),x => [x + 1])]);

}
}
```

Comment: Do you enter a new item at the bottom of the list, assign a priority number and the list sorts? How is auto sort done? Or do you insert a row between 1 and 2, and enter the new item 2?

Comment: @TheWizEd Yes, I enter a new item at the bottom of the list, when I press enter the day's date appears in the cell to the right.  Then I enter the priority number and the list auto sorts to put it into it's proper place numerically.  The date entering and the auto sorting are done using Apps Script code.

Answer (score 0):

#### Adjusting priorities

You'll probably have to play with this a bit but you can adjust the priorities fairly easily and the function will resort them and number them consecutively starting from one as the final step so they always number 1 through n

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('Entry');
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == 'Sheet0' && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value) {
    e.source.toast('Validation')
    e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(new Date());
    let prg = sh.getRange("C2:C" + sh.getLastRow());
    prg.clearDataValidations();
    let pl = prg.getValues().flat();
    let l = [...Array.from(new Array(pl.length + 2).keys(), x => x)];
    //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(l));
    let rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(l).build();
    prg.setDataValidation(rule);
  }
  if (sh.getName() == 'Sheet0' && e.range.columnStart == 3 && e.range.rowStart > 1) {
    e.source.toast('Sort')
    sh.getRange("A2:C" + sh.getLastRow()).sort({ column: 3, ascending: true });
    //Logger.log([...Array.from(new Array(sh.getLastRow()-1).keys(),x => [x + 1])]);
    sh.getRange("C2:C" + sh.getLastRow()).setValues([...Array.from(new Array(sh.getLastRow()-1).keys(),x => [x + 1])]);
  }
}
```

If you have a better idea about how to do it please share

Comment: This is great @Cooper.  Thank you very much.